# Getting, "missing `from` in implementation"

Tags: rust, traits

When I try to compile code, I'm getting

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `from`
  --> src/api/error.rs:25:1
   |
25 | impl From<UserError> for warp::reply::Json {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `from` in implementation
   |
   = help: implement the missing item: `fn from(_: T) -> Self { todo!() }`
```

My code is pretty simple,

```
impl From<UserError> for warp::reply::Json { todo!() }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you need to write or stub the implementation of the [`From` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) to compile which is currently,

```
pub trait From<T> {
    pub fn from(T) -> Self;
}
```

So that would look like,

```
impl From<UserError> for warp::reply::Json {
  fn from(err: UserError) -> Self {
    todo!()
  }
}
```